# When I press 'w', my character moves on top, but not forward

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I press 'w' my character more like jumps away on top, same things with 'a' and 'd', but character moves left or right. It seems like a bug, but I've got two error messages:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
> Gamekit3D.PlayerController.Awake () (at Assets/3DGamekitLite/Scripts/Game/Player/PlayerController.cs:149)

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
> Gamekit3D.PlayerController.OnDisable () (at Assets/3DGamekitLite/Scripts/Game/Player/PlayerController.cs:172)

here's my code:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using UnityEngine;

    public class PlayerCharacter : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Animator animator;

        public Rigidbody playerPhysics;

        public float jumpPower = 12f;
        public float groundCheckDistance = 0.3f;
        private bool isGrounded;
        public float groundCheckDistanceSaved;
        private float turnAmount;
        public float forwardAmount;

        private void Start()
        {
            groundCheckDistanceSaved = groundCheckDistance;
        }

        public void Move(Vector3 move, bool jump)
        {
            move = transform.InverseTransformDirection(move);
            move = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(move, Vector3.up);
            turnAmount = Mathf.Atan2(move.x, move.z);
            forwardAmount = move.z;
            isGrounded = Physics.Raycast(transform.position + (Vector3.up * 0.1f), Vector3.down, out _, groundCheckDistance);

            if (isGrounded)
            {
                HandleGroundedMovement(jump);
            }
            else
            {
                HandleAirborneMovement();
            }
            ApplyExtraTurnRotation();
            UpdateAnimator();
        }

        void UpdateAnimator()
        {
            animator.SetFloat("Forward", forwardAmount, 0.1f, Time.deltaTime);
            animator.SetFloat("Turn", turnAmount, 0.1f, Time.deltaTime);
            animator.SetBool("OnGround", isGrounded);
            animator.SetFloat("Jump", playerPhysics.velocity.y);
        }

        void HandleAirborneMovement()
        {
            playerPhysics.AddForce(Physics.gravity);
            groundCheckDistance = playerPhysics.velocity.y < 0 ? groundCheckDistanceSaved : 0.01f;
        }

        void HandleGroundedMovement(bool jump)
        {
            if (!jump || !isGrounded)
                return;

            playerPhysics.velocity = new Vector3(playerPhysics.velocity.x, jumpPower, playerPhysics.velocity.z);
            isGrounded = false;
            groundCheckDistance = 0.1f;
        }

        void ApplyExtraTurnRotation()
        {
            var turnSpeed = Mathf.Lerp(180, 360, forwardAmount);
            transform.Rotate(0, turnAmount * turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }

        public void OnAnimatorMove()
        {
            if (!isGrounded || Time.deltaTime < 0.001f)
                return;

            var velocity = (animator.deltaPosition) / Time.deltaTime;

            velocity.y = playerPhysics.velocity.y;
            playerPhysics.velocity = velocity;
        }
    }
```

**I got asked for posting for player controller script, here's part of this script:**

```
// Called automatically by Unity when the script first exists in the scene.
        
void Awake()

        {

            m_Input = GetComponent<PlayerInput>();
            m_Animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
            m_CharCtrl = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

            meleeWeapon.SetOwner(gameObject);

            s_Instance = this;
        }

        // Called automatically by Unity after Awake whenever the script is enabled. 
        void OnEnable()
        {
            SceneLinkedSMB<PlayerController>.Initialise(m_Animator, this);

            m_Damageable = GetComponent<Damageable>();
            m_Damageable.onDamageMessageReceivers.Add(this);

            m_Damageable.isInvulnerable = true;

            EquipMeleeWeapon(false);

            m_Renderers = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();
        }

        // Called automatically by Unity whenever the script is disabled.
        void OnDisable()
        {
            m_Damageable.onDamageMessageReceivers.Remove(this);

            for (int i = 0; i < m_Renderers.Length; ++i)
            {
                m_Renderers[i].enabled = true;
            }
        }

        // Called automatically by Unity once every Physics step.
        void FixedUpdate()
        {
            CacheAnimatorState();

            UpdateInputBlocking();

            EquipMeleeWeapon(IsWeaponEquiped());

            m_Animator.SetFloat(m_HashStateTime, Mathf.Repeat(m_Animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime, 1f));
            m_Animator.ResetTrigger(m_HashMeleeAttack);

            if (m_Input.Attack && canAttack)
                m_Animator.SetTrigger(m_HashMeleeAttack);

            CalculateForwardMovement();
            CalculateVerticalMovement();

            SetTargetRotation();

            if (IsOrientationUpdated() && IsMoveInput)
                UpdateOrientation();

            PlayAudio();

            TimeoutToIdle();

            m_PreviouslyGrounded = m_IsGrounded;
        }
```

Comment: The problem refers to `PlayerController` rather than `PlayerCharacter`, can you please post relevant code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)